# Print Tab Spaces using htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I use the following PHP Code to print the entire contents of a file in a window:

```
<?php
$pathin = // contains absolute path of a file
$lines = file($pathin);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    $php_array[$line_num]="<b>".($line_num+1)."</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />";
    echo $php_array[$line_num];
}
$html = implode('', file($pathin));
$trimmed = file($pathin, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
?>
```

Here is the printscreen of the contents that gets printed:

[image]

`$pathin` stores the absolute path of the file. However I find that `htmlspecialchars($line)` ignores the tabs spaces in a file and as a result all proper indentation is lost. Is there a way to print the contents of a file restoring the tabs spaces and thereby restoring the indentation?

Comment: how about `<pre>` tag ?

Comment: also, `nl2br` before `htmlspecialchars()` perhaps

Comment: @HAL9000 >> `<pre>` tag produces the result but with large line breaks. Any hint to reduce the linebreaks?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy >> `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line))` doesn't restores the indentation.

Comment: Thanks @HAL9000 and @Ohgodwhy >> Using `<style>
pre { 
display: inline; 
line-height: 0px;
}
</style>` and `$php_array[$line_num]="<b>".($line_num+1)."</b> : <pre>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line)) . "</pre>";` solves my problem.